# To be at work at vs to be at work for

Tags: grammar

I am a programmer so please excuse my poor grammar...

A friend recently posted a question on Facebook asking "which sentence is correct?

1) I have To be to work for 7:30
2) I have to be at work for 7:30

I said it's neither, and the correct sentence is

3) I have to be at work at 7:30

My friend is saying both 2 and 3 are both grammatically correct.

Can someone help me understand the differences between each of them and which ones are grammatically correct?

Comment: All three are technically correct.  #3 is the most idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks -  “for 7:30” just sounds all kinds of wrong to me.  It would mark the speaker as a non-native in my mind.  Either “at 7:30” or “by 7:30” is idiomatic.

Comment: @Jim - Depends on where you work.  "For 7:30" could mean "for the 7:30 shift" or some such.

Comment: @Jim You say "It would mark the speaker as a non-native" - "non-native" of where?! Different varieties of English are spoken in many different countries. "I have to be at work for 7:30" sounds perfectly normal & acceptable to this native English speaker living in England!

Comment: @TrevorD - Really???  I am very surprised. “for ***a/the*** 7:30 shift/meeting/appointment- sure. Even, the meeting is set *for* 7:30.  But just being at work for 7:30??? I can’t rationalize how that could make sense.  Do you have any insight?

Comment: @Jim To be honest, it sounds so natural that I haven't given it any thought. Yes, "for a 7:30 start/shift/meeting/whatever" would be implicit - but need not be mentioned.  Likewise, "I have to be there for 7:30" would be perfectly acceptable in the context of discussing going to an evening social event or similar.

Comment: @TrevorD - Another option I thought of:  I have to be at work ’fore  7:30.

Comment: @Jim  No. It's somewhat colloquial and it's "I have to be there for [a meeting or other 'event' starting at] 7:30".  So, in practice, I have to be there somewhat prior to 7:30 in order to be ready for the start of the event.  Conversely, "I have to be there **at** 7:30" *could* mean that there is something happening at 7:30 that requires my presence: it need not imply anything about whether that is at the beginning, middle, end of, or even outside, my normal working day: merely that my presence is required at that time. But, to be fair, that usage would be unusual.

Comment: @Jim Having re-thought about whether 'for' in this context as could be a contraction of 'before', I suppose it *could* be, but that would have to have been a long way back.  Also, it's not an expression one would normally see written, as it's more colloquial .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say what you have said: "I have to be at work at 7:30." I'd use "at" before "work" because we use it to indicate the place where something happens. From "English Grammar in Use" by R.Murphy:

[image]

And "at" is used for the time of day: at 7:30, at 5 p.m (to mean when **exactly** something happens).

However, we do use "to" after the verb to be sometimes. For example, "He hasn't been **to** London." But normally we don't use "to" with the verb "to be" because "to" is used when indicating the place that someone or something visits, **moves towards**, or points at. So, I don't see the reason why we have to say "I have to be to work."

If something is planned **for** a particular time, it is planned to happen then (e.g. The party was scheduled for 7:00). But it's not what your sentence is about. You have to be at work at a specific time. I agree with Hot Lick's comment, though. If by "7:30" you mean the 7:30 shift, "for 7:30" is possible.

As I understand it, in the given sentence "at" should be used before "work" and before "7:30".